# Autohotkey will prematurely end loop during execution

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, autohotkey

I've written an AutoHotkey script that allows me to run a SQL query at the cursor's current position in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012. And it works--most of the time anyway.

The implementation uses a sort of delta movement to determine when it's reached the top of a SQL query block or the top of the window. It then selects downward until it reaches the bottom of the window or bottom of the block in the same fashion. Afterwards, it presses F5 to run the script that is highlighted.

Here's the script:

```
$F5::
    ; first check that current line isn't blank (the cursor has to be on some text)
    Send, {Home}
    hltext := SelectNextChar()
    If hltext = `r`n
    {
        ; return to current position
        Send, {Left}
        Return
    }

    ; move cursor up until it gets to the top of the text block

    ; get first length for future comparisons
    Send, {End}
    Send, {Shift Down}{Home}{Shift Up}
    Send, ^c
    StringLen, slctSize, clipboard

    ; begin checking lengths to see if there is still 'movement'
    Loop
    {
        Send, {Shift Down}{Left}{Home}{Shift Up}
        Send, ^c

        ; if the new length is the same then we've hit the top and can break out
        StringLen, temp, clipboard
        IfEqual, slctSize, %temp%
        {
            Send, {Left}
            Break
        }

        ; if we have hit a blank space then we can stop here as well
        firstChar := SubStr(clipboard, 1, 1)
        If firstChar is space
        {
            Send, {Left}{Down}
            Break
        }

        ; if neither one of these conditions are met, continue on
        slctSize = %temp%
        Sleep, 50
    }

    ; select down until blank space or end of file

    Send, {Shift Down}{End}{Shift Up}
    Send, ^c
    StringLen, slctSize, clipboard

    Loop
    {
        Send, {Shift Down}{Right}{End}{Shift Up}
        Send, ^c

        StringLen, temp, clipboard
        IfEqual, slctSize, %temp%
        {
            Break
        }

        ; if we have hit a blank space then we can stop here as well
        lastChar := SubStr(clipboard, 0)
        If lastChar is space
        {
            Break
        }

        ; if neither one of these conditions are met, continue on
        slctSize = %temp%
        Sleep, 50
    }

    ; execute!
    Send, {F5}
    ; place cursor at end of last line
    Send, {Right}
Return


SelectNextChar()
{
    Send, {LShift Down}{Right}{LShift Up}
    Send, ^c
    return %clipboard%
}
```

These movements--up and then down--will sometimes end prematurely, causing the query not to be fully selected when F5 is pressed. For small queries this isn't a problem; for large queries spanning more than ~10 lines, it becomes quickly apparent that something is going on.

I've tested placing `Sleep, 500` in the loops, and it *seems* to do the trick, but the whole point of this script was to make testing queries on the fly a lot faster. If I'm waiting more than 2 or 3 seconds for it to (hopefully) highlight, then what makes it quicker than my old strategy, i.e. manually highlighting with my mouse?

To be clear, the larger queries **are** run for the most part, but the process is not fast enough to warrant usage and there's no guarantee that they will fully highlight before execution. I also understand that my implementation is inherently O(x^2). But if I were to run the script on full blast (`SetKeyDelay, -1`), that wouldn't be a problem.

Any thoughts on the matter or is it just a limitation of the OS/program/AHK?

Also, is it just me or is SO's AHK syntax highlighting severely broken?

**Update:** Here's an updated script with the suggested edits:

```
SendMode, Input ; Very fast but gives unpredictable results at low sleep speeds
SetBatchLines, -1

$F5::
    ; first check that current line isn't blank (the cursor has to be on some text)
    Send, {Home}
    hltext := SelectNextChar()
    If hltext = `r`n
    {
        ; return to current position
        Send, {Left}
        Return
    }

    ; move cursor up until it gets to the top of the text block

    ; get first length for future comparisons
    Send, {End}
    Send, {Shift Down}{Home}{Shift Up}
    Send, ^c
    SleepAfterCopy()
    StringLen, slctSize, clipboard

    ; begin checking lengths to see if there is still 'movement'
    Loop
    {
        Send, {Shift Down}{Left}{Home}{Shift Up}
        Send, ^c
        SleepAfterCopy()

        ; if the new length is the same then we've hit the top and can break out
        StringLen, temp, clipboard
        IfEqual, slctSize, %temp%
        {
            Send, {Left}
            Break
        }

        ; if we have hit a blank space then we can stop here as well
        firstChar := SubStr(clipboard, 1, 1)
        If firstChar is space
        {
            Send, {Left}{Down}
            Break
        }

        ; if neither one of these conditions are met, continue on
        slctSize = %temp%
    }

    ; select down until blank space or end of file

    Send, {Shift Down}{End}{Shift Up}
    Send, ^c
    SleepAfterCopy()
    StringLen, slctSize, clipboard

    Loop
    {
        Send, {Shift Down}{Right}{End}{Shift Up}
        Send, ^c
        SleepAfterCopy()

        StringLen, temp, clipboard
        IfEqual, slctSize, %temp%
        {
            Break
        }

        ; if we have hit a blank space then we can stop here as well
        lastChar := SubStr(clipboard, 0)
        If lastChar is space
        {
            Break
        }

        ; if neither one of these conditions are met, continue on
        slctSize = %temp%
    }

    ; execute!
    Send, {F5}
    ; place cursor at end of last line
    Send, {Right}
Return


SelectNextChar()
{
    Send, {LShift Down}{Right}{LShift Up}
    Send, ^c
    return %clipboard%
}

SleepAfterCopy()
{
    Sleep, 50
}
```

**Update 2:** Here's the version that includes the `ClipWait` per @Sidola. Thus it runs as fast as possible. This update also includes logic to make sure that if you had something copied before hand, it isn't obliterated because of our overuse of the clipboard. And finally, it takes into account any indents or spaces at the beginning/ end of the lines:

```
SendMode, Input ; Very fast but gives unpredictable results at low sleep speeds
SetBatchLines, -1

#IfWinActive ahk_exe Ssms.exe

$F5::
    ; Save current clipboard material and restore it at the end
    before = %clipboard%

    ; first check that current line isn't blank (the cursor has to be on some text)
    Send, {Home}
    clipboard =
    hltext := SelectNextChar()
    If hltext = `r`n
    {
        ; return to current position
        Send, {Left}
        Return
    }

    ; move cursor up until it gets to the top of the text block

    ; get first length for future comparisons
    Send, {End}
    Send, {Shift Down}{Home}{Home}{Shift Up}
    clipboard =
    Send, ^c
    SleepAfterCopy()
    StringLen, slctSize, clipboard

    ; begin checking lengths to see if there is still 'movement'
    Loop
    {
        Send, {Shift Down}{Left}{Home}{Home}{Shift Up}
        clipboard =
        Send, ^c
        SleepAfterCopy()

        ; if the new length is the same then we've hit the top and can break out
        StringLen, temp, clipboard
        IfEqual, slctSize, %temp%
        {
            Send, {Left}
            Break
        }

        ; if we have hit a blank space then we can stop here as well
        firstChar := SubStr(clipboard, 1, 1)
        If firstChar = `r
        {
            Send, {Left}{Down}
            Break
        }



        ; if neither one of these conditions are met, continue on
        slctSize = %temp%
    }

    ; select down until blank space or end of file

    Send, {Shift Down}{End}{Shift Up}
    clipboard =
    Send, ^c
    SleepAfterCopy()
    StringLen, slctSize, clipboard

    Loop
    {
        Send, {Shift Down}{Right}{End}{Shift Up}
        clipboard =
        Send, ^c
        SleepAfterCopy()

        StringLen, temp, clipboard
        IfEqual, slctSize, %temp%
        {
            Break
        }

        ; if we have hit a blank space then we can stop here as well
        lastChar := SubStr(clipboard, 0)
        If lastChar = `n
        {
            Break
        }

        ; if neither one of these conditions are met, continue on
        slctSize = %temp%
    }

    ; execute!
    Send, {F5}
    ; place cursor at end of last line
    Send, {Right}

    ; restore clipboard
    clipboard = %before%
Return

+F5::
    Send, {F5}
Return


SelectNextChar()
{
    Send, {LShift Down}{Right}{LShift Up}
    Send, ^c
    SleepAfterCopy()
    return %clipboard%
}

SleepAfterCopy()
{
    ClipWait
    ; Sleep, 30
}
```

Comment: I have no clue if this would actually effect your script in particular, but have you tried using `SendMode, Input`? It's usually faster than the default `SendMode, Event`. Simply put it at the top of your script in the auto-exec section.

Comment: @Sidola It does have an effect: the script attempts to move at the speed of light! It only highlights the first or second line before it tries to execute with F5.

Comment: Aw, that's a shame. I'm not exactly familiar with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012, but am I correct in assuming you've got several queries in a single view with some line-breaks between each? If so, would it be possible for you to supply a sample of the data you're using with the script? It's hard to test it without knowing how your data looks.

Comment: @Sidola Unfortunately I cannot provide a sample as it is the property of my company; any SQL queries should work though. What you could do, if you were inclined, is to visit [w3schools.com's SQL section](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) and run it there. All you would need to do is remove the `Send, {F5}` at the end of the script. Also, SQL Server Management Studio 2012 reacts to some of the inputs a bit differently than Notepad did; if that's the case with your web browser you may have to change which keys are sent to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it ends prematurely is probably due to the copy-command not having enough time to properly update the clipboard before you go to work on it.

The best way to handle this is to clear the clipboard before copying anything, and relying on [`ClipWait`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ClipWait.htm) to tell us when something has been copied. Alternatively let it time-out to tell us that nothing has been copied.

[`ClipWait`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ClipWait.htm) also allows us to detect the top and bottom of a document without checking for duplicates, as we'll simply be waiting for a time-out.

Below is a working example that is as fast as I could make it.

**Note however**: This script only works with programs whose copy-command behaves normally. Meaning if you copy without a selection, nothing gets copied. While trying this I discovered that some programs don't have this behavior, and as such this script won't work with those programs. In those cases you will have to resort to checking duplicates some way or another.

```
SendMode, Input
SetBatchLines, -1

Esc::ExitApp

$F5::
    ; Check if the line we're currently at is just a line break
    if (isLineBreak( getFirstChar() ))
        return

    ; Get to the top of the document
    traverseText("up")
    ; Get to the bottom
    lineCount := traverseText("down")
    ; Select everything
    selectAllLines(lineCount)
return

; --- Only functions below ---

selectAllLines(lineCount) {
    Send, {LShift Down}
    Loop, % lineCount {
        Send, {Up}
    }
    Send, {Home}
    Send, {LShift Up}
} 

traverseText(direction) {
    Loop {
        selectLine(direction)
        thisLine := copyText()

        ; If it's just a line break, we're out
        if (isLineBreak(thisLine)) {

            ; If we were going up we want to move down once first
            if (direction = "up")
                Send, {Down}

            break
        }

        ; If nothing was copied, we're out
        if (!thisLine)
            break

        i := A_Index ; Keep track of how many lines we've moved passed
    }

    ; If we had a line break beneath us
    ; we need to add one to the counter
    if (thisLine)
        i++

    return i ; Return the amount of lines we traversed
}

isLineBreak(value) {
    return value = "`r`n"
}

getFirstChar() {
    Send, {Home}+{Down} ; Home, Shift + Down
    char := copyText()
    Send, {Left}
    return char
}

selectLine(direction) {
    Send, % direction = "up" ? "{Home}" : "{End}" ; Ternary operator 
    Send, {LShift Down}
    Send, % direction = "up" ? "{Up}" : "{Down}" ; Ternary operator 
    Send, {LShift Up}
}

copyText() {
    Clipboard := ""
    Send, ^c
    ClipWait, 0.2 ; Time-out after 200ms
    return Clipboard
}
```

Comment: That actually works wonders! I have noticed that since `SendMode, Input` is still enabled, it will sometimes hang up and give some weird results as before, but with it disabled it runs at a respectable pace. May I ask what `SetBatchLines, -1` does?

Comment: Nice to hear, you could also try playing with the sleep values instead of `SendMode, Input`, as that should provide a huge speedboost.

`SetBatchLines` determines how fast a script will run. See docs here: http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SetBatchLines.htm

Comment: Yeah, I've added the `SendMode, Input` back and changed the `Sleep, ` to `50`. Getting really good speed now. Thanks!

Comment: @akappel I kept fiddling with the script and came up with a version that uses `ClipWait`, I think this is the best way to handle it, as it shouldn't be able to fail copying now. See the edits in my answer if you want more info.

Comment: That's awesome! I was just looking at `ClipWait`'s documentation. On it's way to the top of the query, does it hang up on two identical lines?

Comment: @akappel Yeah, the only way to detect the top/bottom of a document seems to be by checking for duplicates, I couldn't get around that problem. I'll have a look later and clean up the answer a bit as well, the current examples are kind of messy.

Comment: @akappel So I figured out a way to deal with the duplicates. I've updated my answer with the most clear solution I could come up with. Hopefully it'll be of some use to you.

Comment: Your code looks great! really cleaned up. I went ahead and implemented the `ClipWait` into my code, as well as some other things to take indents into account. It now works about perfect! I updated my question with this final version.